# Is there a list of all nodes in blender?

Tags: node-editor

How do I get started working with nodes and is there a complete list of nodes so I can view them?

Comment: Here's a great list of geo nodes, maintained by Quellenform: [Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/273541/60486)

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is. However the list is much too long for an answer here. I have included a list of all the node types. There are many more nodes under each type classification. Click on the type you want to learn about. Or click the title for the section to view the index on the wiki.

### [Compositor Node Types:](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/index.html#node-types)

- [**Inputs**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/input/index.html)
- [**Outputs**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/output/index.html)
- [**Color**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/color/index.html)
- [**Vector**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/vector/index.html)
- [**Filters**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/index.html)
- [**Converters**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/converter/index.html)
- [**Mattes**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/matte/index.html)
- [**Distortion**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/distort/index.html)
- [**Groups**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/groups.html)
- [**Layouts**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/layout/index.html)

---

### [Material Node Types:](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/index.html)

- [**Input**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/index.html)
- [**Output**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/output/index.html)
- [**Color**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/color/index.html)
- [**Vector**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/index.html)
- [**Convertors**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/converter/index.html)
- [**Groups**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/groups.html)
- [**Open Shading Language**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/osl.html)
- [**Shader**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/index.html)
- [**Texture**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/index.html)

---

### [Geometry Node Types](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/index.html#node-types)

*[from editor: since it changes a lot currently, I recommend this list maintained by Quellenform: [**Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/273541/60486)]*

---

As for getting used to working with them, explore and experiment! You will stumble across all sorts of goodies. You can also try an online shading tutorial. Once you get better with nodes, I would suggest you try reaching a specific result, i.e. a Wood material, a Galvanized Steel material, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The above links went stale. Not surprising given how much has happened in the years since original posting. The wiki seems to have pretty good lists. Here is a start:

[Shader Nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/index.html)

[Compositing Nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/index.html#node-types)

[Geometry Nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/index.html#node-types)