# Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?

Tags: geometry-nodes

It's not hard to lose track of all the *Geometry Nodes* in *Blender*, especially since names and function have changed over time.

...But honestly, it's getting pretty tedious.

Many tutorials talk about nodes that I can't find in my version, and the [official Blender documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/) doesn't help me here to get an overview of the nodes and their history.

Also an internet search does not give me any useful results on the subject.

Hence the question:

*Which nodes can be found in which Blender version?*

> **Note:** This question (and answer) serves as a target for the recurring question regarding undiscoverable nodes, which is asked again and again in various forms, and is intended to show as simply and clearly as possible how nodes have changed over time.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

## Geometry Nodes Overview

<sub>(Status as of Nov 30, 2023)</sub>

Here you can find a complete list of *Geometry Nodes* available in different Blender versions in tabular form.

> Since here unfortunately a restriction of the number of characters is set to 30000, it was not possible for me to add the links to the respective documentation.
>
> Therefore I have additionally published this list in HTML format, which contains further links directly to the respective documentation of the individual nodes:
> [Geometry Nodes Overview](https://geometry-nodes-overview.docs.quellenform.at/)

### Attribute Nodes

|  | 3.0 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 3.3 LTS | 3.4 | 3.5 | 3.6 LTS | 4.0+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Attribute Statistic | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Blur Attribute | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Capture Attribute | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Domain Size | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Transfer Attribute | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | - | - | - | - |
| Remove Named Attribute | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Store Named Attribute | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

**Additional changes since version 3.4:**

- The `Transfer Attribute` node has been removed and split into multiple more specific nodes:

  - The `Sample Index` node retrieves data from specific geometry elements by index.
  - The `Sample Nearest` node retrieves the indices from the closest geometry elements
  - The `Sample Nearest Surface` node interpolates a field input to the closest location on a mesh surface.

  On that topic, check out this post explaining how to use the new nodes:
  [Where is Transfer attribute in 3.4?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/276088/145249)

**Additional changes since version 3.5:**

- The `Store Named Attribute` node can now store 2d vector attributes

#### Addendum: Replaced Attribute Nodes

Some nodes were completely replaced by other nodes after version *2.93* due to the introduction of [Fields](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/fields.html):

|  | 2.92 | 2.93 LTS | 3.x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Attribute Clamp | - | Yes | Clamp |
| Attribute Color Ramp | Yes | Yes | Color Ramp |
| Attribute Combine XYZ | - | Yes | Combine XYZ |
| Attribute Compare | Yes | Yes | Compare |
| Attribute Convert | - | Yes | Transfer Attribute (3.1+) Interpolate Domain (3.3+) |
| Attribute Fill | Yes | Yes | Capture Attribute (3.1+) Store Named Attribute (3.2+) |
| Attribute Map Range | - | Yes | Map Range |
| Attribute Math | Yes | Yes | Math |
| Attribute Mix | Yes | Yes | Mix |
| Attribute Proximity | - | Yes | Geometry Proximity |
| Attribute Randomize | Yes | Yes | Random Value |
| Attribute Remove | - | Yes | Remove Named Attribute (3.2+) |
| Attribute Sample Texture | - | Yes | Image Texture |
| Attribute Separate XYZ | - | Yes | Separate XYZ |
| Attribute Vector Math | Yes | Yes | Vector Math |

### Color Nodes

|  | 2.92 | 2.93 LTS | 3.0 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 3.3 LTS | 3.4 | 3.5 | 3.6 LTS | 4.0+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Color Ramp | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Combine RGB | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes ⇲ | - | - | - | - | - |
| Combine Color | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| MixRGB * | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes ⇲ | - | - | - | - |
| Mix Color * | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| RGB Curves | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Separate RGB | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes ⇲ | - | - | - | - | - |
| Separate Color | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

<sub>* The nodes `MixRGB` and `Mix Color` are referred to as "Mix" in the title of the node.</sub>

### Curve Nodes

|  | 3.0 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 3.3 LTS | 3.4 | 3.5 | 3.6 LTS | 4.0+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Curve Length | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Curve to Mesh | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Curve to Points | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Deform Curves on Surface | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Fill Curve | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Fillet Curve | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Interpolate Curves | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Resample Curve | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Reverse Curve | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Sample Curve | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Subdivide Curve | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Trim Curve | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Curve Handle Positions | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Curve Tangent | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Curve Tilt | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Endpoint Selection | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Handle Type Selection | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Is Spline Cyclic | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Spline Length | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Curve Parameter | Yes ⇲ | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| Spline Parameter | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Spline Resolution | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Set Curve Normal | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Set Curve Radius | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Set Curve Tilt | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Set Handle Positions | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Set Handle Type | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Set Spline Cyclic | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Set Spline Resolution | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Set Spline Type | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

**Additional changes since version 3.5:**

- The `Trim Curves` node now has a selection input

### Curve Primitive Nodes

|  | 3.0 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 3.3 LTS | 3.4 | 3.5 | 3.6 LTS | 4.0+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Arc | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Bézier Segment | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Curve Circle | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Curve Line | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Curve Spiral | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Quadratic Bézier | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Quadrilateral | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Star | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

### Curve Topology Nodes

|  | 3.4 | 3.5 | 3.6 | 4.0+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Offset Point in Curve | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Curve of Point | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Points of Curve | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

### Geometry Nodes

|  | 2.92 | 2.93 LTS | 3.0 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 3.3 LTS | 3.4 | 3.5 | 3.6 | 4.0+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bounding Box | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Convex Hull | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Delete Geometry | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Duplicate Elements | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Geometry Proximity | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Geometry to Instance | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Join Geometry | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Merge by Distance | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Raycast | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Sample Index | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Sample Nearest | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Separate Components | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Separate Geometry | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Transform | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Set ID | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Set Position | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Index of Nearest | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes |

### Input Nodes

|  | 2.92 | 2.93 LTS | 3.0 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 3.3 LTS | 3.4 | 3.5 | 3.6 LTS | 4.0+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boolean | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Collection Info | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Color | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Image | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Image Info | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Integer | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Is Viewport | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Material | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Object Info | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Self Object | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Scene Time | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| String | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Value | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Vector | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Index | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Named Attribute | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Normal | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Position | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Radius | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| ID | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Random Float * | Yes | Yes * | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |

<sub>* The node `Random Float` has been renamed to `Random Value` and has been moved to the category "Utilities" since version 3.0.</sub>

**Additional changes since version 3.5:**

- The `Named Attribute` input node now has an "Exists" output to tell whether the attribute exists

### Instances Nodes

|  | 3.0 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 3.3 LTS | 3.4 | 3.5 | 3.6 LTS | 4.0+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Instance on Points | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Instances to Points | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Rotate Instances | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Scale Instances | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Translate Instances | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Realize Instances | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Instance Rotation | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Instance Scale | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

### Material Nodes

|  | 3.0 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 3.3 LTS | 3.4 | 3.5 | 3.6 LTS | 4.0+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Replace Material | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Material Index | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Material Selection | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Set Material | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Set Material Index | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

### Mesh Nodes

|  | 2.92 | 2.93 LTS | 3.0 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 3.3 LTS | 3.4 | 3.5 | 3.6 LTS | 4.0+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dual Mesh | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Edge Paths to Curves | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Edge Paths to Selection | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Extrude Mesh | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Flip Faces | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Boolean | Yes | Yes ⇲ | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| Mesh Boolean | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Mesh to Curve | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Mesh to Points | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Mesh to Volume | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Sample Nearest Surface | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Sample UV Surface | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Scale Elements | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Edges Split | Yes | Yes ⇲ | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| Split Edges | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Subdivide | - | Yes ⇲ | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| Subdivide Mesh | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Subdivision Surface | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Triangulate | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Edge Angle | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Edge Neighbors | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Edge Vertices | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Edges to Face Groups | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Face Area | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Face Neighbors | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Face Set Boundaries | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes ⇲ | - | - | - |
| Face Group Boundaries | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Face is Planar | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes ⇲ | - | - | - | - |
| Is Face Planar | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Is Face Smooth | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes |
| Is Edge Smooth | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes |
| Is Shade Smooth | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Mesh Island | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Shortest Edge Paths | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Vertex Neighbors | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Set Shade Smooth | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

### Mesh Primitive Nodes

|  | 2.93 LTS | 3.0 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 3.3 LTS | 3.4 | 3.5 | 3.6 LTS | 4.0+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cone | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Cube | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Cylinder | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Grid | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Icosphere | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Circle | Yes ⇲ | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| Mesh Circle | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Line | Yes ⇲ | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| Mesh Line | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| UV Sphere | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

### Mesh Topology Nodes

|  | 3.4 | 3.5 | 3.6 LTS | 4.0+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Corners of Face | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Corners of Vertex | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Edges of Corner | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Edges of Vertex | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Face of Corner | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Offset Corner in Face | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Vertex of Corner | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

### Output Nodes

|  | 3.0 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 3.3 LTS | 3.4 | 3.5 | 3.6 LTS | 4.0+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Viewer | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

### Point Nodes

|  | 2.92 | 2.93 LTS | 3.0 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 3.3 LTS | 3.4 | 3.5 | 3.6 | 4.0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Distribute Points in Volume | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Point Distribute | Yes | Yes ⇲ | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| Distribute Points on Faces | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Points | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Points to Vertices | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Points to Volume | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Points to Curves | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes |
| Set Point Radius | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

#### Addendum: Replaced Point Nodes

Some nodes were completely replaced by other nodes after version *2.93*:

|  | 2.92 | 2.93 LTS | 3.x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Align Rotation to Vector | Yes | Yes | Align Euler to Vector |
| Point Distribute | Yes | Yes | Distribute Points on Faces |
| Point Instance | Yes | Yes | Instance on Points |
| Point Rotate | Yes | Yes | Rotate Euler |
| Point Scale | Yes | Yes | Vector Math (*Scale*) |
| Point Separate | Yes | Yes | Separate Geometry |
| Point Translate | Yes | Yes | Set Position |

### Text Nodes

|  | 3.0 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 3.3 LTS | 3.4 | 3.5 | 3.6 LTS | 4.0+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Join Strings | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Replace String | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Slice String | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Special Characters | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| String Length | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| String to Curves | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Value to String | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

### Texture Nodes

|  | 3.0 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 3.3 LTS | 3.4 | 3.5 | 3.6 LTS | 4.0+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brick Texture | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Checker Texture | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Gradient Texture | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Image Texture | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Magic Texture | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Musgrave Texture | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Noise Texture | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Voronoi Texture | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Wave Texture | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| White Noise | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

**Additional changes since version 3.5:**

- The `Image Texture` node has a new mirror extension type

### Utilities Nodes

|  | 2.92 | 2.93 LTS | 3.0 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 3.3 LTS | 3.4 | 3.5 | 3.6 LTS | 4.0+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Accumulate Field | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Align Euler to Vector | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Boolean Math | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Clamp | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Float Compare | Yes | Yes ⇲ | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| Compare Floats | - | - | Yes ⇲ | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| Compare | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Field at Index | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes ⇲ | - | - | - |
| Evaluate at Index | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Float Curve | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Float To Integer | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Interpolate Domain | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes ⇲ | - | - | - |
| Evaluate on Domain | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Map Range | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Math | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Mix | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Random Value | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Rotate Euler | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Rotate Vector | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes |
| Axis Angle to Rotation | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes |
| Euler to Rotation | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes |
| Rotation to Euler | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes |
| Rotation to Quaternion | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes |
| Quaternion to Rotation | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes |
| Invert Rotation | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes |
| Rotation to Axis Angle | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | Yes |
| Switch | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

### Vector Nodes

|  | 2.92 | 2.93 LTS | 3.0 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 3.3 LTS | 3.4 | 3.5 | 3.6 LTS | 4.0+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Combine XYZ | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Separate XYZ | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Vector Curves | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Vector Math | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Vector Rotate | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

### Volume Nodes

|  | 2.93 LTS | 3.0 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 3.3 LTS | 3.4 | 3.5 | 3.6 LTS | 4.0+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Volume Cube | - | - | - | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Volume to Mesh | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

### UV Nodes

|  | 3.3 LTS | 3.4 | 3.5 | 3.6 LTS | 4.0+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pack UV Islands | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| UV Unwrap | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

### Group Nodes

|  | 2.92 | 2.93 LTS | 3.0 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 3.3 LTS | 3.4 | 3.5 | 3.6 LTS | 4.0+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group Input | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Group Output | - | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

### Hair Nodes

|  |  | 3.5+ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Deformation:** |  |  |
|  | Blend Hair Curves | Yes |
|  | Displace Hair Curves | Yes |
|  | Frizz Hair Curves | Yes |
|  | Hair Curves Noise | Yes |
|  | Roll Hair Curves | Yes |
|  | Rotate Hair Curves | Yes |
|  | Shrinkwrap Hair Curves | Yes |
|  | Smooth Hair Curves | Yes |
|  | Straighten Hair Curves | Yes |
|  | Trim Hair Curves | Yes |
| **Generation:** |  |  |
|  | Duplicate Hair Curves | Yes |
|  | Generate Hair Curves | Yes |
|  | Interpolate Hair Curves | Yes |
| **Guides:** |  |  |
|  | Braid Hair Curves | Yes |
|  | Clump Hair Curves | Yes |
|  | Create Guide Index Map | Yes |
|  | Curl Hair Curves | Yes |
| **Read:** |  |  |
|  | Curve Info | Yes |
|  | Curve Root | Yes |
|  | Curve Segment | Yes |
|  | Curve Tip | Yes |
|  | Hair Attachment Info | Yes |
| **Utility:** |  |  |
|  | Attach Hair Curves to Surface | Yes |
|  | Redistribute Curve Points | Yes |
|  | Restore Curve Segment Length | Yes |
| **Write:** |  |  |
|  | Set Hair Curve Profile | Yes |

### [Node-Based Tools](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/tools.html)

With version 4.0, geometry nodes can now also be created as tools, which are then available in the main menu.

|  | 4.0+ |
| --- | --- |
| 3D Cursor | Yes |
| Face Set | Yes |
| Selection | Yes |
| Set Face Set | Yes |
| Set Selection | Yes |

---

### Addendum: Math Nodes

Most mathematical operations hide behind the nodes [Math](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/math.html) and [Vector Math](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/vector/vector_math.html), which can be found in the category **Utilities** and **Vector** respectively.

So if you see a node that does not appear with its name in the above list, it is almost certainly one of these two nodes whose property has been set to a specific mathematical operation, and thus also shows the corresponding name in the title.

#### Vector Math Nodes

The operations available in [Vector Math](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/vector/vector_math.html) are:

|  | 2.92 | 2.93 LTS | 3.0+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Add | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Subtract | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Multiply | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Divide | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Multiply Add | - | - | Yes |
| Cross Product | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Project | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Reflect | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Refract | - | Yes | Yes |
| Faceforward | - | Yes | Yes |
| Dot Product | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Distance | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Length | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Scale | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Normalize | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Wrap | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Snap | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Floor | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Ceil | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Modulo | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Fraction | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Absolute | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Minimum | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Maximum | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Sine | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Cosine | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Tangent | Yes | Yes | Yes |

#### Math Nodes

The operations available in [Math](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/math.html) are as follows (these are equally available in all versions):

|  | All Versions |
| --- | --- |
| **Functions:** |  |
|  | Add |
|  | Subtract |
|  | Multiply |
|  | Divide |
|  | Multiply Add |
|  | Power |
|  | Logarithm |
|  | Square Root |
|  | Inverse Square Root |
|  | Absolute |
|  | Exponent |
| **Comparison:** |  |
|  | Maximum |
|  | Less Than |
|  | Greater Than |
|  | Sign |
|  | Compare |
|  | Smooth Minimum |
|  | Smooth Maximum |
| **Rounding:** |  |
|  | Round |
|  | Floor |
|  | Ceil |
|  | Truncate |
|  | Fraction |
|  | Modulo * |
|  | Wrap |
|  | Snap |
|  | Ping-Pong |
| **Trigonometric:** |  |
|  | Sine |
|  | Cosine |
|  | Tangent |
|  | Arcsine |
|  | Arccosine |
|  | Arctangent |
|  | Arctan2 |
|  | Hyperbolic Sine |
|  | Hyperbolic Cosine |
|  | Hyperbolic Tangent |
| **Conversion:** |  |
|  | To Radians |
|  | To Degrees |
|  | Clamp |

* In Blender version 4.0, the *Modulo* node has been split into two options:

- *Truncated Modulo* : Outputs the remainder once the first value is divided by the second value.
- *Floored Modulo*: Returns the positive remainder of a division operation.

---

...and if you still see a node somewhere in a screenshot/tutorial that is not listed here, then it is most likely an individually assigned title.

Comment: Outstanding work !

Comment: That's some dedication :))

Comment: Now you've got me thinking about how to scrape these tables with a script... did you do that?

Comment: @RobinBetts After I put the list together manually, the same thought occurred to me ;-) ...I think I will automate this in the future.

Comment: Wow! This is a great overview and awesome work! The only problem I still have when watching tutorials that create cool things with nodes that don't exist in my version is, how to translate those nodes from one to the other? Sometimes of course, newer versions have new features that were not possible before - well, that's progress. But sometimes nice things are made with old nodes and I just don't know how to reproduce them with the new ones.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Good point! ...I have now tried to bring this missing information into it. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: @quellenform Have no time to check right now, but good luck with this  I guess sometimes you have to combine nodes to get same results from previous older nodes... seems very tedious work.

Comment: Totally missed this post, great quality content. We need more of this.

Comment: @RobinBetts One step closer to a possible automation: I have now written the document as reStructuredText and packed all links uniformly into one file: https://github.com/quellenform/blender-geometry-nodes-overview/blob/main/Documentation/links.rst This makes it possible to better recognize and correct outdated links in the future.

Comment: Stunning work, q. You have such an organized mind! This should be a standard appendix to the docs. (But. arghh, now you've got me going down a ReST rabbit-hole :)  )