# Object instance on single point using vertex group. Blender 3.2.2

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry, vertex-groups, instances, point-clouds

I'm a complete noob with blender and just started learning geo nodes. I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHGokQoqVb8&t=421s and I know it's for an old version of Blender but its driving me mad that I can't get the simplest thing to work. The guy creates a vertex group using the plane and then uses the single point in the middle to instance a cube but the nodes he uses are no longer the same and I managed to get it only this close (definitely learned a lot while searching how to do it though) I would really appreciate it if you guys help me.

The tutorial:
[image]

My attempt
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the help guys! And also thank you for explaining it so clearly! I've definitely learned a couple of new things from your answers alone!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Blender 3.2* you have the possibility to directly access individual attributes of your geometry.

A vertex group is such an attribute.

Normally a vertex group is nothing more than a float value between $0$ and $1$, which can also be directly converted to an integer or boolean value and used as a selection.

And this is exactly how you can solve the puzzle with version 3.2:

[image]

Here I use the node `Separate Geometry`, which gets the vertex group as selection in the input, and outputs two separate geometries in the output, on which I then instantiate the objects.

---

But there is another solution:

[image]

Here I first put the objects to be instantiated into a collection.

With the node `Collection Info` these are fetched and made available as instances by activating *Separate Children* in alphabetical order.

If I then put the vertex group into the input *Instance Index* of the node `Instance on Points` and additionally select the option *Pick Instance*, the same result is achieved as before.

Since the vertex group contains a value from $0$ to $1$, either one or the other object is selected.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2)*</sub>

---

**PS:** To get an overview of the nodes in different Blender versions, I recommend this post:
[Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/273542/145249)

Answer (score 2):

Quellenform has [answered your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/273561/35559), so this post isn't meant to be accepted, it's just a side-note to point out that if it's the *pattern* you're after, it can be made with old-style modification of any quad surface.. e.g. from a plane:

[image]

1. *Subdivide* (Simple)
2. *Bevel* (Vertices, with material offset)
3. *Edge Split* and *Solidify*

[image]

4. *Displace* (Normals, to separate tiles)
5. *Bevel* (Edges)

... Which might make for a flexible workflow, in some circumstances.

[image]

[image]