# What node replaces the attribute proximity node in blender

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

I've followed a tutorial on YouTube https://youtu.be/pHPokgBgYN8 but it's from an older version of blender so the new geometry nodes are not working what node can i use instead of attribute proximity

Comment: Just search for „proximity „

Comment: ...Search here for "Proximity": [Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/273542/145249)

Answer (score 0):

> OK, just to be able to mark the question as solved:

The node `Attribute Proximity` has been replaced by the node `Geometry Proximity`:

[image]

You can find an overview of the nodes and their changes here:
[Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/273542/145249)