# Morphism using geometry nodes without the Transfer node

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

In this new version of blender3.4 they take away the transfer node. How can we make a morphism without using it?

Comment: Use **Sample Index** node

Comment: This answer may be helpful too: [Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/273542/145249)