# Converting some old point distribute point instance nodes to the new version of Blender 3.4.1

Tags: geometry-nodes, text-object

I'm trying to convert some old nodes **point distribute, point instance, randomize attribute nodes** to the new version of Blender 3.4.1 but I'm having some difficulty of converting the functionality over.

**Old Nodes:**

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Example Followed:
https://youtu.be/wFnuWrcs04E

**Attached blend file bellow:**
[image]

**Update: Dec 26 2022:**

I went through the link John Easton mentioned but it seems to be missing options like a checkbox that does what the old **Whole Collection option disables / enables does.**

[image: img4]

[image: img5]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273541/cant-find-the-node-which-node-is-available-in-which-blender-version

Comment: @John Easton Thanks it seems to be missing options Like a checkbox that does what the old Whole Collection option disables / enables does.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with geometry nodes yet so someone else will have to answer that one.

Comment: @JohnEason This function has been replaced in the node `Instance on Points` with the inputs *Pick Instances* and *Instance Index*.

Comment: Ok thanks. It was actually @RickT who was asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do this.  I thought I'd post my findings for the next person.

**Box:**

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

=========================================
**Glyph / totem**

[image: img3]

[image: img4]