# Distribute Points on Faces and Geometry Proximity

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

The sphere in the screenshot below was done in an older version of Blender. How can I recreate this using the current nodes in Blender like the Distribute Points on Faces node and Geometry Proximity Node?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible variant would be the following setup:

[image]

Basically, the node `Geometry Proximity` replaces the obsolete node `Attribute Proximity`.

Furthermore, in this example I use the node `Store Named Attribute` to store an attribute in the geometry, which I then read and use again in the shader with `Attribute`.

By the way, you can find an overview of the nodes and their changes over time here:
[Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273541/cant-find-the-node-which-node-is-available-in-which-blender-version/)

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

you can use this node setup:

[image]

to get this:

[image]

Comment: This method doesn't work in Blender 3.4.1.