# Geometry Proximity problem

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I've been trying to copy the *Geometry Proximity* method from [Distribute Points on Faces and Geometry Proximity](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283167/) using *Ico Spheres* and I'm not getting the same results shown in the screenshot below.
[image: Icospheres]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To see the colors you have to switch the _3D Viewport_ to either _Material Preview_ or _Rendered_ display mode. You are in _Solid_ mode.

Comment: This question actually looks like it could be solved by toggling the *Viewport Shading*, as 
@GordonBrinkmann correctly pointed out. If that is not the solution, then please share your blend file. For now, though, I'm closing the question, because if that was the solution, then the title and content of the question are unrelated to the problem and misleading. Thanks for your understanding!

Comment: Here's the file. https://www.dropbox.com/t/YGgeWtGrip7SHLkS

Comment: Ah, OK, Sorry, that was indeed a problem I may have caused, because I had hidden the additional options in the `Geometry Proximity` node in this example. These should be set to *Points* in this case (I have updated the screenshot accordingly. Also, you would still have to assign a material!

Comment: @RobertHintz Your question is basically a duplicate of the Quellenform answer you've linked to, it's just that you weren't quite diligent in recreating it verbatim. So it's better to keep this q closed I think but I do wanna point 4 little issues in your setup. You haven't actually set the material, your Geo Proximity should be in Points mode (hidden in the Quellenform answer so it's understandable you missed that), you should not link the original sphere to Join Geometry and of course, you should be in Material Preview or Render mode: https://i.imgur.com/B61bgFc.png

Comment: @Kuboå Thank you for commenting so beautifully and in detail!

Comment: @quellenform Whatever keeps me from doing my actual job :)

Comment: @Kuboå Thank you!