# Can't find scale node

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I tried to find the *Scale* node in shader editor (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Search*), but nothing appear in the search bar. How to add this node?

Comment: There are math and vector math with multiply function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273541/cant-find-the-node-which-node-is-available-in-which-blender-version)

Comment: 'Scale' is one of the _Vector Math_ options. @Gorgious .. quellenform's  answer you linked to is truly heroic :)