# Where can I find the "Density" attribute in Blender 3.6.1?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

This node from Blender 2.92.0. I need the attribute "Density". Where is it?

Comment: Geometry Nodes changed between Blender 2.9x and 3.x. a lot. The Attributes concept was dropped and Fields were introduced. In a later 3.x version, Attributes were made available again. You probably looking for the *[Distribute Points on Faces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/point/distribute_points_on_faces.html)* node.

Comment: The density attribute (I am talking about the one entered in this node) was some thing that used to be created by the user. It was not some attribute that was output by the node. This user defined attribute (which can could be named anything) is what you enter in the node to control the density of the points generated.

Answer (score 0):

The node you are looking for is called `Distribute Points on Faces` since Blender 3.0:

[image]

Here you will also find an overview of all nodes and their changes over time:
[Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273541/)