# Python scripting a custom Geometry Node to generate another Geometry Nodes

Tags: python, scripting, geometry-nodes, customization

I am scripting a custom Geometry Nodes(hosted by “Cube”) with python to initiate another Geometry Node from another object(i.e. Plane). I tried this using a template searched from the internet. I didn’t bother to edit the names and other stuff but trying to add a function to test the above purpose. It can generate a new geo node under the modifier stack but it is not yet initiated. The “new” button is remained “un-pressed”. Thus, I need to add a script to “press” the “new” button as follows:

```
bpy.ops.node.new_geometry_node_group_assign(override, modifier="nnn")
```

Attached blender file as reference: [image]

However, when I do the override on the following for assigning a new geometry nodes(equivalent to press the “NEW” button on the modifier stack for the geo node, Blender either crashed quit or remained the geo node uninitiated:
[image: code snapshot with lines number]
bpy.ops.node.new_geometry_node_group_assign(override, modifier="nnn")

I tried many times and tweak the scripts to avoid crash but still in vain.
Can someone be kind enough to help me solve this issue?
[image: Try to use the Cube's geometry node to generate another for the object Plane node when adding "is Rendered View"]
[image: the geo node created for Plane remain uninitiated but Blender sometimes crashed when adding the above script: 'new_geometry_node_group_assign(override, modifier="nnn" ' during adding the node "is Rendered View"]

Comment: The .blend file contains the default cube, with Geometry Nodes that do nothing, with the node tree having the Group Input directly connected to the Group Output, and a free-floating (disconnected) "is Viewport" node. There's also a plane, a light and a camera. There's a script in the *Scripting* workspace that seems to introduce the "is Viewport" ("is rendered view" is the opposite?) functionality in Blender version that didn't yet support it. According to the [quellenform's list](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/273541/60486) that would be B2.92.

Comment: So I figure you want to create custom nodes in Python? That's the way the question should be phrased then, concentrate on what you want to achieve, not on the technicalities ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem ). Asking to fix bugs is off-topic to this site.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I tried to rephrase the title and content to explicitly express I wanted to script the custom geometry node. On the other hand, you suggest it is a bug but I am not sure whether it is a bug or just my incapability to initiate a geometry node by python but it needs to be initiated from another geometry node because I need to "apply the geo node" finally.

Answer (score 0):

The two errors are are `bpy.ops.node.new_geometry_node_group_assign` does not recognize `modifier` as a keyword. Another one is, using the `override` dictionary returns **{'CANCELLED'}**. To fix this, replace `bpy.ops.node.new_geometry_node_group_assign(override, modifier = 'nn')` with,

```
with bpy.context.temp_override(**override):
    bpy.ops.node.new_geometry_node_group_assign()
```

Changing the modifier name of the modifier can be achieved by running `obj.modifiers.active_name = 'nn'`.

You may want this behavior, but I don't know if you want to create new modifiers per update of the node (on creation, on new sockets, or on link). You may just do all this stuff in the `init` function of the node.