# Geo nodes are not there in the add menu

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to learn geometry nodes and I feel like it would be very helpful to know where all the nodes are in the add menu rather than having to search by name.

Specifically in the tutorial I'm following, the instructor is placing a set position node, which he is clearly finding in add/geometry. When I access that menu it is not there along with what appears to be several other nodes that I don't see.

If I search by name set position pops right up. Is there some setting I don't know about which is hiding functionality in the add menu?

Comment: Geometry Nodes have evolved a lot over the last two years, and so the menu structure has changed again and again. The best thing to do is to follow the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/index.html) of the version you are using. Additionally there is a nice overview of the nodes here: [Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273541/cant-find-the-node-which-node-is-available-in-which-blender-version/273542#273542)

Comment: thanks, I'll try that

Comment: Just for completeness, in 3.3 LTS it's directly on the Add > Geometry submenu, whereas in 3.51 and 3.6 LTS it's under Add > Geometry > Write > Set Position. So many new nodes have been added that the addition of extra submenu levels is necessary to fit everything in nowadays!

Answer (score 0):

*Geometry Nodes* have evolved a lot over the last two years, and so the menu structure has changed again and again.

It is best to follow the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/index.html) of the version you are using, because it always shows exactly the structure that corresponds to your particular Blender version.

In version 3.4, for example, the node is listed under *Add > Geometry*:

[image]

And as of version 3.5, you can find the node under *Add > Geometry > Write*:

[image]

Also, if you're looking for a node and want to know what version it's available in, here's a nice overview of the nodes: [Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273541/cant-find-the-node-which-node-is-available-in-which-blender-version/273542#273542)