# Attribute sample texture in Blender 3.0?

Tags: modeling, texturing, geometry-nodes, instances

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNI9XGXPDPs&ab_channel=ThinkSci-Fi) (time 1.55). I use Blender 3.6.2

The tutor uses *Attribute Sample Texture* in this case, I do not know how to obtain the same result. Does anyone know how to do it?

Expected result on the left and mine on the right part.
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. It would be better if you explain your main goal a bit more, instead of sending users to another site by using a link

Comment: Hello, Quentin.. welcome... Emir has said it. For the Stack Exchange format, please edit this question to make it self-contained. You can include links for supplementary reference, but the post has to work, even if they break. State your goal, and your starting-point, as simply as you can. You can illustrate with screen-grabs, and if it helps, share your .blend as far as it goes, on https://blend-exchange.com/, copying the link into your post. Edit, and we can re-open for you.

Comment: From Blender 2.92 to Blender 3.6, several GN nodes have been changed, removed or replaced, and others have been added. Have a look here => [Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/273541/107598) It has a good overview and ccording to the 2nd table "Addendum: Replaced Attribute Nodes", the "Attribute Sample Texture" node was replaced by the "Image Texture" node in Blender 3.x.