# How to replace Attribute Vector Math in this situation?

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics, vector

Here I am following a tutorial ([the hand reveal](https://youtu.be/cKDC5YE-26k?feature=shared&t=390)) where Entagma uses the Attribute Vector Math in Geometry Nodes in Blender 2.93.0 beta but I don't see it anymore in Blender 4.0 and, my question is, how can I replace it ?
Here you can find the screenshot from the tutorial and the screenshot with my datas :

from Entagma's tutorial : https://freeimage.host/i/entegma.JTygpKG
my datas : https://freeimage.host/i/JTyrIRV
link to the blender file : https://file.io/DdV4dFg96mnL

I also couldn't find the Point Instance node, I "solved" this by dragging the cube file directly into the Geometry Nodes board (see Object Info) then I connected it on Instance on Points as seen on the screenshot but, I'm not sure if it's the correct/best way to do it ?

kindly

Comment: This might be helpful: [Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273541/#273542)

Comment: yes I know that the Vector Math replaces it but (I forgot to mention that, I'm sorry) it looks nothing like the Attribute Vector Math therefore it needs to be completed with other nodes in order to achieve the same function as the Attribute Vector Math, correct me if I'm wrong... Kindly

Comment: With the fields workflow there is no concept of attribute vector math node anymore, you simply plug the vector math to the field you want to compute

Answer (score 1):

Following [Entagma's formulation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKDC5YE-26k&t=390s)..

In GN Fields, to store an attribute on the points of the modified object representing  a clamped linear (0->1) gradient between the locations of external objects A and B, you would now do this:

[image]

For this behaviour:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Alright, thank you. I have followed what you've done precisely but now my object is gone. 

https://i.postimg.cc/nrcsQBCN/diamond-gone.jpg 

To be honest I'm completely lost, being new to Blender it's hard to connect the dots and understand the Geometry Nodes universe.

Comment: Hi, @Nexgen...  _Instance on Points_ **replaces** the provided points with the instances. If you want the underlying geometry to be part of the output, you have to join it back in explicitly: https://imgur.com/a/lWaRbCp.. (maybe it should have been called _Points to Instances_ )