# GN: How to replace Interpolate domain node with Transfer Attribute domain for 3.2?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I did some research about which nodes to use in which version from this [amazing link from quellenform](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273541/cant-find-the-node-which-node-is-available-in-which-blender-version) shoutout to them thank you so much it was very helpful.And I'm going from a 3.3 version geonodes to **3.2** where there is no [Interpolate Domain](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.3/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/interpolate_domain.html) node. Based on the link it seems I have to use the [Transfer Attribute](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/transfer_attribute.html) node instead.

[image]

I tried replacing it and trying all the options, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

[image]

Blend **3.3** file
[image]

Comment: Hello, Megan, thanks for  a well-illustrated post. I think you might set folks up to answer a little better, though, if you could edit to  open with a sentence describing what you want to interpolate in this particular case? (A specific example often makes the generality easier to grasp)

Comment: sorry i didn't specify i found the solution to use Capture Attribute node. Not sure why this was not mentioned in quellenforms documentation? honestly i'm not so good with geonodes.

Comment: Turns out to be no problem :) Glad you found it!  You can accept your own answer, after a while.

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer [in the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.3/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/interpolate_domain.html) to use [Capture Attribute](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.3/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/capture_attribute.html) node

[image]

It now works.

[image]