Replacemet for Transfer Attribute for Blender 4.0?
So I was following this tutorial of Bad Normals (enter link description here). So if you start watching the video form 18mins, he uses the transfer attribute. I am using blender 4.0 and the transfer attribute don't exist. I tried sample index and sample nearest node but it is not working as it should and not creating the same results. Can anyone help me out on this?

Helpful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273541/cant-find-the-node-which-node-is-available-in-which-blender-version/

But using it in a curve an it is not helping out in any way....
